# How to find city and state from the latitude and longitude in R

Tags: r, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have a file which contains latitude and longitude. I need to get city and state information for that. How to do it in R. Which library to use for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `revgeocode()` from [ggmap](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ggmap/docs/revgeocode).

If you also specify the `output` argument and set it to `"more"`, the function returns a nice data frame that holds among other things information on the respective city and state.

**Example:**

```
library(ggmap)
geo_information <- revgeocode(c(-97.358112, 37.683829), output = "more")

geo_information$locality
# [1] Wichita
# Levels: Wichita

geo_information$administrative_area_level_1
# [1] Kansas
# Levels: Kansas
```

Comment: This is no longer valid in my `ggmap` (version `3.0.0`).